# Domain redirection based on Geo - AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, redirect, amazon-ec2, amazon-route53

I have basically 2 hosted zones **.com and **.co.in. For all the incoming traffic from India , if user browses .com it should automatically redirect to co.in . How do we do this in AWS . I read this http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/resource-record-sets-values-geo.html#rrsets-values-geo-location and implemented in co.in hosted zone but does not seem to work. Also I think there should be some domain redirection set up in .com but cant find where we can do in Route53

Regards
Raghav

Comment: So you want to redirect traffic from India on the .com, but not all traffic to going to the .com, correct?

Comment: Thats correct. All traffic to .com from India should redirect to co.in

Answer (score 3):

To simplify my solution, I'm going to refer to these domains as `example.com` and `example.co.in`. Here's how I'd solve this:

**S3 Bucket for `example.com`**:

```
Static Website Hosting:
  Redirect Requests:
    Target Bucket or Domain: example.co.in
```

Note the region that this bucket is created in, such as `us-east-1`, we'll need that later

**Route 53 Record Set for `example.com` For India**:

```
Type: CNAME
Value: example.co.in.s3-static-website-[region].amazonaws.com
Routing Policy: Geolocation
  Location: India
  Set ID: India Redirect
```

**Route 53 Record Set for `example.com` Not India**:

You'd set your `Type` and `Value` as normal

```
Routing Policy: Geolocation
  Location: Default
  Set ID: Regular Traffic
```

Further Reading:

- [Geolocation Resource Record Sets](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/resource-record-sets-values-geo.html)
- [How Do I Redirect Requests to an S3 Bucket Hosted Website to Another Host?](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/redirect-website-requests.html)

Comment: Sure will try that. Thank you !

Comment: Thanks Jamie. That works . Now the only issue is for SEO reasons we want to do 302 (temporary) rediret instead of permanent 301 redirect. Cant find a place where that can be configured . Would be great if you can help.

Comment: I was able to do that by adding redirection rule in s3 webhosting . Seems to work

Comment: Awesome, was my answer sufficient? If so, is it worth accepting?

Comment: Hey @Jamie , I did the setup as mentioned in the article. 1) Created s3 bucket as www.example.com 2) Set up Geo based Redirect from www.example.com to www.example.co.in for India 3) Set up default for www.example.com .  It works well when I browse www.example.com from India (i,e redirects to www.example.co.in) but if I browse www.example.com with https, the site does not load and does not redirect to co.in domain. Is it something to do with https ?

Comment: My site is already behind cloudfront with custom origin and I guess directly putting s3 as source in Route53 does not go well with https. But do I need to create another distribution then?